# c# remove items from combobox based on MaxLength

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, combobox

So I have a combobox and I have it so that based on other criteria the MaxLength is edited. The problem is that the MaxLength property only applies to typed inputs and not items from the combobox. So is there a way to remove items from the combobox based on their length and add them back if the length increases again? here is my code:

```
private void titleText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int colourNum;
        int textType = 1;

        if (titleTextType.Text == "Material")
            textType = 1;
        else if (titleTextType.Text == "Material Flipped")
            textType = 2;
        else if (titleTextType.Text == "Normal")
            textType = 3;
        else if (titleTextType.Text == "3D")
            textType = 4;
        else textType = 0;


        if (titleTextColour.Text == "Red")
            colourNum = 49;
        else if (titleTextColour.Text == "Green")
            colourNum = 50;
        else if (titleTextColour.Text == "Yellow")
            colourNum = 51;
        else if (titleTextColour.Text == "Blue")
            colourNum = 52;
        else if (titleTextColour.Text == "Cyan")
            colourNum = 53;
        else if (titleTextColour.Text == "Pink")
            colourNum = 54;
        else if (titleTextColour.Text == "White")
            colourNum = 55;
        else if (titleTextColour.Text == "Black")
            colourNum = 48;
        else if (titleTextColour.Text == "Yale Blue")
            colourNum = 59;
        else if (titleTextColour.Text == "Light Yellow")
            colourNum = 58;
        else colourNum = 0;

        byte[] colourArray = new byte[2]
                {
                    (byte) 94,
                    (byte) colourNum
                };
        byte[] prefixArray1 = new byte[5]
                {
                    (byte) 94,
                    (byte) textType,
                    (byte) 0x3D,//125decmax
                    (byte) 0x3D,//125decmax
                    (byte) titleText.Text.Length
                };


        if (textType == 3 && colourNum == 0)
        {
            titleText.MaxLength = 23;
        }
        else if (textType == 3 && colourNum != 0)
        {
            titleText.MaxLength = 21;
        }
        else if (textType == 1 && colourNum == 0 || textType == 2 && colourNum == 0)
        {
            titleText.MaxLength = 18;
        }
        else if (textType == 1 && colourNum != 0 || textType == 2 && colourNum != 0)
        {
            titleText.MaxLength = 16;
        }
        else if (textType == 4)
        {
            titleText.MaxLength = 3;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance c:

Comment: what about using the [length property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx) on string ?

Comment: Are you trying to limit the number of items shown or filter the items by it's length?

Comment: for(int x = titleText.Items.Count; x > 0; x--) { if(titleText.Items[x].Text.Length > titleText.MaxLength) titleText.Items.RemoveAt(x); }  or something like that - I don't have my IDE open. It might be faster to use a lambda expression to compare lengths - I miss c#

Comment: @user1274820, I cannot use the Text.Length property for any items of titleText. Sorry i'm not very good at programming :c.

Comment: add .ToString() ? comboBox1.Items[0].ToString().Length works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, will be easier to demonstrate code here.

My comboBox is named comboBox1.

This test code adds Test1 - Test20 and then removes them based on their length:

```
for (int x = comboBox1.Items.Count-1; x >= 0; x--)
    if (comboBox1.Items[x].ToString().Length > comboBox1.MaxLength)
        comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(x);
```

[image]
Your code should look like this:

```
for (int x = titleText.Items.Count-1; x >= 0; x--)
    if (titleText.Items[x].ToString().Length > titleText.MaxLength)
        titleText.Items.RemoveAt(x);
```

Comment: Always happy to help if I can c: